# Anime.js - Prevent animation from playing again

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

```
let gameInit = anime.timeline({
  easing: "easeInOutExpo",
  duration: 3000,
});

gameInit
  .add({
    targets: ".buttondiv",
    scale: [0, 1],
    delay: 1000,
    duration: 750,
  })
  .add(
    {
      targets: "#srps-div",
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateY: [-50, 0],
      duration: 750,
    },
    "-=200"
  )
  .add(
    {
      targets: "#srps-tag",
      opacity: [0, 1],
      duration: 750,
    },
    "-=800"
  )
  .add(
    {
      targets: "#code-tag",
      opacity: [0, 1],
      duration: 750,
    },
    "-=950"
  );

gameInit.finished.then(function () {
  let buttonBounce = anime.timeline({
    duration: 1200,
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    loop: true,
    direction: "alternate",
    delay: 3000,
  });

  buttonBounce.add({
    targets: ".buttondiv",
    scale: [1, 1.25],
  });
});

document.querySelector(".buttondiv").onclick = function(){gameStart()};

gameStart = () => {
  let startGameAni = anime.timeline({
    duration: 1250,
    easing: "easeOutBack",
    direction: 'fowards',
    loop: false
  });

  startGameAni
    .add({
      targets: ".buttondiv",
      translateX: [0, -3000],
      opacity: [1, 0]
    })
    .add({
      targets: "#choiceprompt",
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateX:[3000, 0]
    },);
};
```

This is my current animejs file.

gameInit are a couple of simple animations that are called once the user goes to the website. Once gameInit is done, buttonBounce will start and do a short scaling effect every 3 seconds.

When the player hits the button, it moves out of the frame to the left. The choiceprompt comes in from the right. This is done with startGameAni.

Please check a short video here with the issue:

https://streamable.com/cyidwj
[EXPIRES IN 24 HOURS]

**My questions:**

- How do I keep the prompt on screen? When I click anywhere near the choiceprompt, especially in the middle, it starts the animation again. I don't want that. It magically lets the button reappear again and does the animation again with the prompt appearing again. How can I force anime to not replay the animation upon a mouseclick?

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed it myself. For those that are interested:

Even if the animation sends something off screen, the element is still there, perhaps hidden, on its original position and may interfere with other elements that are closeby. I've changed the initial position in the animation to be offscreen and bring it onscreen during the animation.

When the animation containing the swipe was finished, I've added another animation in the timeline which sent the unused elements 3000 pixels above the
main element. Now it was out of the way, and everything worked like it should:

```
    document.querySelector(".buttondiv").onclick = function () {
  gameStart();
};

gameStart = () => {
  let startGameAni = anime.timeline({
    duration: 1200,
    easing: "easeInOutBack",
    direction: "fowards",
    loop: false,
  });

  startGameAni
    .add({
      targets: ".buttondiv",
      translateX: [0, -3000],
      opacity: [1, 0],
    })
    .add({
      targets: "#choiceprompt",
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateX: [3000, 0],
    })
    .add({
      targets: ".buttondiv",
      marginTop: [0, -3000],
    });
};
```